# cannot connect to amazon ec2 rhel7 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2

Sometime back everything was working fine and I was able to login via ssh. Suddenly the load on my instance went as high as 25, and I was't able to connect anymore. The error message I got was :

```
sh: connect to host xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx port 22: Connection refused
```

I looked for possible solutions and tried rebooting my instance from aws management console. It didn't work. I also stopped my instance and started it again after sometime. This too didn't work. I tried using the java login console that they provide on their control panel, that too gave the same error.
I tried a more verbose response using the command :

```
ssh -vvv root@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

This resulted in the output below :

```
OpenSSH_6.2p2, OSSLShim 0.9.8r 8 Dec 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] port 22.
debug1: connect to address xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx port 22: Connection refused
ssh: connect to host xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx port 22: Connection refused
```

I am guessing the sshd service somehow stopped. Is there anyway I could restart it ?
Also there was this weird thing I noticed last time I logged in. There were 3k+ unsuccessful login attempts since the last successful login (which was a couple of hours back). Could this be the reason why sshd stopped working or could it be the load shooting upto 25?

P.S.: I have port 22 open for all i.p. addresses for ssh under security groups from AWS management console

Comment: 3k+ unsuccessful login attempts? Don't you suspect someone is trying to hack your instance?

Comment: @NomanUrRehman I suspect that, but I made that passwords strong enough to avoid any brute force attacks. Plus I'll allow traffic from a selected few i.p. addresses once I get the ssh up and running

Comment: First off, verify the port is still open for connections using `telnet <your-instance-ip> 22`
What output do you get?

Comment: @NomanUrRehman This is what I get:


`Trying xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx...
Connected to ec2-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.2
Connection closed by foreign host.`

Comment: Remove the IPs from your previous comment, placeholders will do

Comment: I suspect due to so many brute force attempts, your `ssh` connections are being refused as the `sshd` service has that in it's configuration as far as I remember. Start with applying a security group to your instance that allows `ssh` connections only from your IP.

Comment: @NomanUrRehman Did that, still the same response. Will it take some time  for the ssh service to be back and running?